Cookies getting deleted from browser as it refreshes but they are coming in response
When building an application, I have hosted my server on Railway. Now the problem is everything goes good when things are on localhost but when making the request from my vercel app which has permission to do it so, cookies are getting into browser and then fades away.
import User from "../models/userSchema.js";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import Company from '../models/companySchema.js'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import emailValidator from 'email-validator'


export const userSignUp = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, username, password } = req.body;
    // Check if the user already exists
    const emailValidation = emailValidator.validate(email);
    if (!emailValidation) {
      return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Kindly Provide Correct Email' });
    }
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Email Already Registered with this email',
      });
    }
    // Hash the password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    // Create a new user
    const newUser = new User({
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      username,
    });
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    const token = jwt.sign(
      { id: savedUser._id, email: savedUser.email },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      { expiresIn: '2d' } // Set the token expiration to 2 days
    );

    // Set the cookie with a 2-day expiration
    ;
    const expirationDate = new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 2 days from now
    res.cookie('token', token, {
      expires: expirationDate,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true, // Ensure secure attribute for HTTPS
      path: '/', // Set path to root
      sameSite: 'none', // Allow cross-site cookies
    });
  
    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Signup successful',
      user: { email: savedUser.email, isCompanySet: false },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: e.message });
  }
};

export const userSignIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { password, email } = req.body;

  const emailValidation = emailValidator.validate(email)
  if (!emailValidation) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Kindly Provide Correct Email' })
  }

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'No User Found' });
    } else {
      const passwordValidation = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!passwordValidation) {
        return res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid password' })
      }
      const id = user._id;
      const token = jwt.sign({ id, email }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, {expiresIn: '2d'});
      let allCompanies = [];
      const allofficeIds = user.companies;

      const toSendUser = {
        email: user.email,
        isCompanySet: user.isCompanySet,

      }

      for (const office of allofficeIds) {
        try {
          const company = await Company.findOne({ _id: office })

          allCompanies.push(company);
        } catch (e) {
          return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: e.message })
        }
      }
      
      const expirationDate = new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      res.cookie('token', token, {
        expires: expirationDate,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true, // Ensure secure attribute for HTTPS
   // Set path to root
        sameSite: 'none', // Allow cross-site cookies
      });
    
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "User Logged In", allCompanies, toSendUser });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return res.json(e);
  }
}

export const userLogOut = async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  if (!token)
    return res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'Unautorized user' });

  const { id, auth0Id } = jwt.decode(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
 
  res.clearCookie('token');

  try {
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Logout successful' });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error logging out', error: error.message });
  }

}

export const handleRefresh = async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  if (!token)
    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid' });
  const { id, email } = jwt.decode(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
  if (!id || !email) {
    return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Unauthorized user' })
  }
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid' });
    } else {
     
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'User Logged In', user });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: e.message });
  }
}

I want that cookies remain in browser only till they expire or removed forcefully.
